# How to Add Block with Page on the same view?

Tags: views, nodes, taxonomy-terms

Initially, I have displayed the contents in the Block on View. Now I am trying to display Taxonomy Term in the Page ,with Block on the same view.

There is a ADD button in the View, if I add the page for Taxonomy Term in that view, It's showing the same content information for the Page.

How do I add Taxonomy Term for Page and Content for Block on the same View.

Please anyone help me how to sort out this problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, why don't you try 'Attachment' option from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Views, click on +Add button and select `Attachment`. (This part is optional, if you have a view block already created you can just attach that).

Make your attachment look like your block.

Now go to your page view in the FOOTER add `Global: View area` and select your attachment or block.

Comment: Oh, you're fast. I just provided this as a comment. ;)

Comment: I have done your instruction , but there is no change happened in the view. Its still showing only the content of Block